# QLineEdit.text() function makes my program crash, but only when it's in a slot

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

quick Explanation, im still in HS and trying to put together a little project, basically its some kind of messenger app using our school's servers.

Of course, for that, you need a login window, with account management and stuff. The account management part is already done, leaving only the part where i put everything together, connecting the buttons to actions and etc.

So i made slots for that :

[Slots :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI8CU.png)

The problem is that my whole app crashes as soon as i try to read the text in the QLineEdits from the window's slot

(m_nickname and m_password are the two QLineEdit where the username and password are typed in)
(m_login and m_signup are the two buttons to login and signup)

Also, here is my whole class definition if that helps :
[.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtWw6.png)
[.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0bj0.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to help me :-)

Comment: Welcome! Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically, the section on [why you shouldn't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It crash's cause of [segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault).
you didn't assign an address for this two QLineEdits.
what you actually did in constructor is defining another QLineEdit **m_nickname** and **m_password** and your class member variable did not locate in memmory
change your constructor where you define these QLineEdits like this:

instead of

```cpp
QLineEdit *m_nickname = new QLineEdit();
```

write

```cpp
m_nickname = new QLineEdit();
```

and instead of

```cpp
QLineEdit *m_password = new QLineEdit();
```

write

```cpp
m_password = new QLineEdit();
```